# yaml serialization using yamlbeans and fxml properties

Tags: java, serialization, properties, yaml

I'm trying to use YamlBeans to serialize fxml properties. Specificaly a Property. The class has a private property field and the fxml standard getter and setter methods but the information is not saved to the file when serialization occurs.

Entry point:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        Person person = new Person(5);
        YamlSerializer.serialize(person, System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/person.yml");
    }
}
```

Person.java

```
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;

public class Person{
    private Property<Number> age;
    public Person(){
        age = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        age.setValue(3);
    }
    public Person(Number age){
        this.age = new SimpleDoubleProperty(age.doubleValue());
    }
    public Property<Number> ageProperty() {
        return this.age;
    }

    public Number getAge() {
        return this.ageProperty().getValue();
    }

    public void setAge(final Number age) {
        this.ageProperty().setValue(age);
    }
}
```

YamlSerializer.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlReader;
import com.esotericsoftware.yamlbeans.YamlWriter;

public class YamlSerializer {
    public static void serialize(Object object, String path) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(path);
        if(!file.exists())
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        YamlWriter writer = new YamlWriter(new FileWriter(path));
        writer.write(object);
        writer.close();
    }
    public static Object deserialize(String path) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(path);
        if(!file.exists()){
            if(!file.getParentFile().exists())
                if (!file.getParentFile().mkdirs()){
                    System.out.println("Error creating files");
                }
        }
        YamlReader reader = new YamlReader(new FileReader(path));

        return reader.read();
    }
}
```

Output file person.yml:

```
!Person {}
```

[image]

Comment: Should probably mention you are using [YamlBeans](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans).

Comment: It's in the title, but I mentioned it again for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. What does Beans `getProperties` return for your class? This is what [YamlWriter uses](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/yamlbeans/YamlWriter.java#L283).

Turns out [Beans](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/yamlbeans/blob/master/src/com/esotericsoftware/yamlbeans/Beans.java#L113) is finding all the properties, then looking for get/set methods. It looks like it should find your `number` field and then your `setNumber` and `getNumber` methods, but you didn't provide the full class code.

I suggest providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Trying to help someone without that is a shot in the dark and a time waste.

Edit: The way Beans looks for fields, then a matching setter/getter, `Property<Number> age` doesn't work. Beans looks for a setter/getter of type `Property<Number>` and doesn't find them. IIRC it used to use Introspector, but that had to be ripped out because it was missing from Android.

To fix this you would need to patch Beans to be smarter about finding setter/getters without a corresponding field. A PR that does that would be merged.

Comment: I think this is the bit of code that I'm missing and don't quite understand. What am I suppose to be calling getProperties on? Is there some method I'm suppose to use to inform YamlWriter about the FXML beans?

Comment: It appears to be an empty list. Picture added.

Comment: I'v added code that should be easy to paste into a project, assuming you have the .jar for YamlBeans and Fxml installed.

Comment: To make code that can be copy/pasted, use static classes and a main method. Also easier to write/read to/from a string. But that is for next time, I've updated my answer.